# Why is validationengine not working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

Method

```
    alert($("#form1").validationEngine({returnIsValid:true}));
```

return "undefined".

What can i doing not right?

Comment: have you attached the validation engine to the form?

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded and adapted the [demo](http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html) and wrapped the call to validationEngine() in an alert, like you did, and I also got 'undefined' even though everything works fine.  I think that's the standard behaviour so you aren't doing anything wrong.

I couldn't find any docs, but [this blog](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/) shows example code and links to the demo pages.

Answer (score 1):

The API has changed, rather use

```
alert($("#form1").validationEngine('validate'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out possibly one reason that this may occur. (Had this myself prob due to code blindness!)

Was calling the JQuery API from google, loading the validationEngine scripts then by mistake reloading the JQuery API which I presume was voiding the validationEngine script and causing the same error.

Hope this helps.